# Select jsonb key which has the highest value compare to other keys

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have this jsonb column with name "demographics" . It looks like this

```
{

"genre":{"women":10,"men":5} 

}
```

I am trying to create new column which will pick the json key name of the one with highest value;

I tried this.

```
SELECT Greatest(demographics -> 'genre' ->> 'men',
       demographics -> 'genre' ->> 'women')
       AS greatest
FROM   demographics;
```

This one will get `"value"` of the highest one but i want the key name and not the value.
Basically i want that it returns in this case to the row `"women"` as it has higher value;

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack the json object at genre to individual rows using `jsonb_each` and then get the greatest value using `row_number` or any number of methods:

```
with cte as 
(
   select *
        , genre.key as genre
        , row_number() over (partition by id order by value desc) as ord
     from demographics
    cross
     join lateral jsonb_each(demographics->'genre') genre
)
select id, genre, value 
  from cte
 where ord = 1
```

[Here's a working demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b1c3ed3c49f1f11004dadf396a7d0028)

Comment: I am having this error:
`42883] ERROR: function jsonb_each(json) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 181`
Seems that issue might be because the column is actually not "jsonb" but "json" , i tried also with something like json_each but its still erroring :((

EDIT: Seems that "json_each_text" will fix it  but then to get the highest number it will loop all the keys inside . What if i want only to compare several keys?

Comment: If you have more than "woman" and "man" inside that genre key? You can simply add `WHERE genre.key IN ('woman', 'man')` inside the cte, as you would with any filter using SQL.

Comment: Yes i tried to do so but when i add this where clause inside the cte , it doesnt pick the highest values it picks almost random values  :\

Comment: Sorry, this works for the example json object you've shown, I really don't have a magic crystal ball to tell what kind of structure you have in real life to be able to tell you what the answer is.

Comment: `{"he" : {"he_vakiy" : 1660341, "he_naiset" : 853911, "he_miehet" : 806392, "he_kika" : 15999}}`
This is the structure where "he" = genre , "he_naiset" = women ,"he_miehet" = men. Also that list inside "he" is quite long but those are the some of them.

Comment: Ok, but what do you want to get out of this? Greatest value for any of the keys in `he`? Just follow what I did. If you want a subset of the keys from `he`, like `he_naiset` or `he_meihet` then add `WHERE genre.key IN ('he_naiset', 'he_meihet')` inside the cte.